# How to write this stored procedure for SQL Server?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

How to write down this stored procedure for SQL Server?

This error is shown:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
>       Must declare the scalar variable "@name".

```
update login 
        set reg.name=@name
            reg.phone=@phone
            login.email_id=@email_id
            login.pwd=@pwd
            login.role=@role
    from  login  INNER JOIN reg on reg.r_id=login.l_id
    where reg.r_id=@ID
```

please help with this problem.

Comment: The correct syntax depends on the database you're using, which is...?

Comment: Multi-table join syntax depends on the database; you should add tags to indicate which database you're using.  Also you should format the question to be readable; there's a good chance whoever knows the answer won't spend time trying to read it as is.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: sql server 2010

Comment: check my updated answer!!! i have fixed this

Comment: The syntax is correct. But I suspect you are not passing in the parameters to your procedure. Can you share the whole procedure instead of just this query?

Comment: update login 
        set reg.name = @name,
        reg.phone=@phone,
        login.email_id=@email_id,
        login.pwd=@pwd,
        login.role=@role 
    from  login  INNER JOIN reg on reg.r_id=login.l_id
    where reg.r_id=@ID

Answer (score 1):

You can't update columns in multiple tables with a single SQL Statement.
A way of doing this is to create the stored procedure that uses multiple update statements to update multiple tables. 
For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE p_UpdateLogin
(
    @id         INTEGER,
    @name       VARCHAR(10),
    @phone      VARCHAR(10),
    @email_id   VARCHAR(100),
    @pwd        VARCHAR(20), 
    @role       NVARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    BEGIN TRY
        UPDATE login 
           SET login.email_id = @email_id,
               login.pwd      = @pwd,
               login.role     = @role
          FROM login
               INNER JOIN reg
                 ON login.[l_id] = reg.[r_id]
         WHERE reg.[r_id] = @id

        UPDATE reg 
           SET reg.name     = @name,
               reg.phone    = @pwd
         WHERE reg.[r_id] = @id

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [Tran1]
    END CATCH   
END
```

Use the query below to execute the stored procedure:

```
EXEC dbo.p_UpdateLogin @id = 50, @name = 'Saurabh',
     @phone = '1234567890', @email_id = 'demo@email.com',
     @pwd = '******', @role = 'Super';
```

Comment: i am using this up of the example and execute this stored procedures In reg table updated but  In login table not updated

Comment: Stored Procedure is working fine. I have tried it in my db.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update login 
        set reg.name=@name,
        reg.phone=@phone,
        login.email_id=@email_id,
        login.pwd=@pwd,
        login.role=@role 
    from  login  INNER JOIN reg on reg.r_id=login.l_id
    where reg.r_id=@ID`
```

Comment: update login 
        set reg.name=@name
   reg.phone=@phone
   login.email_id=@email_id
   login.pwd=@pwd
   login.role=@role
    from  login  INNER JOIN reg on reg.r_id=login.l_id
    where reg.r_id=@ID

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@name".

Comment: again repeate this error i was put comma and chek it again error

Comment: update login 
        set reg.name=@name,
        reg.phone=@phone,
        login.email_id=@email_id,
        login.pwd=@pwd,
        login.role=@role 
    from  login  INNER JOIN reg on reg.r_id=login.l_id
    where reg.r_id=@ID

Comment: Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 2
Must declare the scalar variable "@name".

Comment: i am added square bracket [ ]  then it was display some like this error!!!!! Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'where'.

Comment: update [login] 
        set [reg].[name] =[@name],
        [reg].[phone]=[@phone],
        [login].[email_id]=[@email_id],
        [login].[pwd]=[@pwd],
        [login].[role]=[@role] 
    from  login  INNER JOIN [reg] on [reg].[r_id]]=[login].[l_id]
    where [reg].[r_id]=[@ID]

Comment: do not [] bracket for variables

Comment: if i am not added bracket [] then it was display in this type of error!!!!Must declare the scalar variable "@name".

Comment: update login 
        set reg.name=@name,
        reg.phone=@phone,
        login.email_id=@email_id,
        login.pwd=@pwd,
        login.role=@role 
    from  login  INNER JOIN reg on reg.r_id=login.l_id
    where reg.r_id=@ID

Comment: i would suggest you run this query on your db directly by replacing the variables with some values and see if works

Comment: plz  see the  example will send me where is replacing the variables